# Папка вверх

Tags: html

Как указать на html что бы загрузило лого из другой папки. Что бы было понятнее:
Сама страница со скриптом находится здесь: site/ru/homeru.html
А лого находится здесь: site/img/logo.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо указать напрямую из корневой директории сайта `<img src="/img/logo.jpg">` (`/` слеш вначале указывает, что папка `img` находится в корневой директории сайта), либо так: `<img src="../img/logo.jpg">` (`../` означает подняться на уровень выше, а затем зайти в папку `img`, где лежит ваш файл `logo.jpg`).